# Combine if statement & countif

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

I have a situation where I need to calculate ontime vs. late in a range of cells.

I use the if statement =IF(N2>K2 +30,"Late","") and this works fine however I would like to combine the countif statement to count the range of cells that contain "late"

Thanks

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by "combining". Are you saying that after you tag all the cells as Late (or blank), you want an overall count of the "Late" records? As in, a separate result? `=COUNTIF(L:L,"Late")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF(N:N>K2+30,1,0))
```

Enter it as array formula by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
updated if you only need to count the number of lates.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting #VALUE! error when I use this =COUNTIF(IF(Q:Q>P2+30,"Late"),"Late") the cells are formatted as general

Comment: I'm getting close.. question why not use =SUM(IF(N:N>K:K+30,1,0))

Comment: you use that if you are to compare eack individual values in `N:N` with `K:K`. so if you are comparing `N2` with `K2` and `N3` with `K3` and so on, then that is the formula to use. I thought you are only comparing the values in `N:N` with a single value in `K:K` which is `K2`.

Answer (score 0):

As per Roberto's comment, if you are actually using a formula to put "Late" in column L for each relevant row you can use a simple `COUNTIF` to count those

`=COUNTIF(L:L,"Late")`

or if you want to use the source data in column N just use COUNTIF with that

`=COUNTIF(N:N,">"&K2+30)`